# How to get mean from plotted data? Going from narrowed plot to data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-analysis

I got this plot by narrowing down the diamond dataset in ggplot2. I did this by sorting for a x limit, cut, etc.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(price,carat,data=diamonds,cut="Ideal",color=clarity) + xlim(2500,3000) + ylim(1,1.6)
```

[image: Price,carat,clarity comparison for diamonds above 1 carat and ideal cut]

How do I extract this data? Does this represent its own subset of the large dataset? So that I can do things like get the mean price, max carat values, etc. ?

Comment: What do you mean about extracting the data? The data is right there in the `diamonds` dataframe (try `print(head(diamonds))`)

Comment: Does that represent the whole dataset? I just want what I am viewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get just the points that appear in that plot:

```
subset(diamonds, price >= 2500 & price <= 3000 & carat >= 1 & carat <= 1.6)
```

Comment: Cool that is what I was looking for. Now I just need to figure out how to order by column high to low, how to find means of columns, how to print just the max or min of a column, how to display text on the plot.

Comment: @chimpsarehungry: Respectively: `d = d[order(d$col), ]`, `colMeans(d)`, `min(d$col)`, `max(d$col)`

Comment: Then the argument for `binwidth= 50` to qplot was completely superfluous and was ignored? I'll delete my noise.

Comment: Yeah I forget to remove that when I was no longer doing a histogram.

Comment: So is that `d = d[order(d$col), ]` mean that d will be my new ordered dataset? Say I name my dataset subs, do I do `d = subs[order(subs$col),]`

Comment: Probably more like `d = subs[order(subs$price), ]`, but yes, exactly

Comment: Cool. And adding the minus sign to subs orders high to low. How do I use colMeans(d) when d has non-numeric columns also. I want to ignore those.

Comment: So I can optimize for carat and price by doing `max(d$carat/d$price)`. Which gives me a number. But now how do I see which diamond that is?

Comment: Nm. This is awesome. I can do `hot = subs[order(-subs$carat/subs$price), ]` . I'm really liking R

Comment: @chimpsarehungry: That's the idea! Incidentally, you can get just the maximum row by doing `subs[which.max(subs$carat/subs$price), ]`